# What is the recommended directory structure for a Rust project?

Tags: rust

Where should one put the sources, examples, documentation, unit tests, integration tests, license, benchmarks *etc*?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Cargo, the official package manager for Rust, [defines some conventions regarding the layout of a Rust crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/guide/project-layout.html):

> ```
> .
> ├── Cargo.lock
> ├── Cargo.toml
> ├── benches
> │   └── large-input.rs
> ├── examples
> │   └── simple.rs
> ├── src
> │   ├── bin
> │   │   └── another_executable.rs
> │   ├── lib.rs
> │   └── main.rs
> └── tests
>     └── some-integration-tests.rs
> ```
>
> - `Cargo.toml` and `Cargo.lock` are stored in the root of your project.
> - Source code goes in the `src` directory.
> - The default library file is `src/lib.rs`.
> - The default executable file is `src/main.rs`.
> - Other executables can be placed in `src/bin/*.rs`.
> - Integration tests go in the `tests` directory (unit tests go in each file they're testing).
> - Example executable files go in the `examples` directory.
> - Benchmarks go in the `benches` directory.
>
> These are explained in more detail in the [manifest description](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-project-layout).

By following this standard layout, you'll be able to use Cargo's commands to build, run and test your project easily. Run `cargo new` to set up a new executable project or `cargo new --lib` to set up a new library project.

Additionally, documentation for libraries is often written in documentation comments (comments that start with `///` before any item, or `//!` to document the parent item). Also, the license is usually put at the root.

Unit tests, as mentioned above, are written in the same module as the functions they're testing. Usually, they're put in an inner module. It looks like this (this is what Cargo generates for a new library with `cargo new --lib`):

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought there would be more to it, somehow, but you have covered everything I asked about.