# How to put these tests in a separate file?

Tags: testing, rust

In `main.rs`, I have some functions that I created to reduce the size of `main()`. Inside them, I use structs and their methods.

```
fn handle_input() {
  // some code
}

fn handle_quit() {
  // some code
) {

fn main() {
   // handle_handle_input() being is used here
   // handle_quit() being is used here
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_handle_input() {
        // some code
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_handle_quit() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Right now, all the tests are passing. However, `main.rs` is becoming too big, so I want to place the tests in their own file.

How can I accomplish this, since I can no longer `use use super::*`? Or maybe the only way is to convert these functions into struct methods and import them in the new test file?

Comment: You can put tests into a `tests` sub-directory, which is a sibling to `src`, however these are a separate crate and generally for integration tests rather than unit tests.  So you are doing the right thing and if `main.rs` is getting too big you might want to consider moving functionality out of it into separate modules, perhaps with their own tests.  For example `my_mod/mod.rs` for the functionality and `my_mod/tests.rs` for the unit tests.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276960/what-is-the-recommended-directory-structure-for-a-rust-project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the module declaration with

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;
```

and then move the tests into the file `tests.rs` in the same directory as `main.rs`. The file name must match the module name in the declaration above. The file `tests.rs` should contain everything inside the curly braces after `mod tests` in your code, excluding the braces.

Generally, having code and tests in the same file is common and intended in Rust, so you could consider splitting up your files into modules in a different way.